# ui bootstrap append dropdown-append-to doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im having this code with a ui-bootstrap dropdown:

```
 <div class="btn-group" style="float: right" uib-dropdown keyboard-nav dropdown-append-to="projectTreeBtn.add">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default projectTreeBtn" ng-click="deleteElement()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Löschen</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default projectTreeBtn" id="projectTreeBtn.add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Hinzufügen</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default projectTreeBtn" uib-dropdown-toggle><span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="projectTreeBtn.add">
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-bind-html="menu.servicepackage"></a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-bind-html="menu.projectphase"></a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-bind-html="menu.servicemodular"></a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-bind-html="menu.task"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want the dropdown to be appended to the second button, but it always appears to be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC4jw.png)

Comment: you can add a class to the dropdown menu and apply css to move the dropdown. This can be done by using position: relative; right : << in pixels>>;